# Skew Buffered Image java

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

I have an image that I want to crop given the corners.
For example

[image: the normal image]

I want to cut just the sudoku puzzle. I have the corners (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4).

Tried this:

```
javaxt.io.Image image = new javaxt.io.Image(bufferedImage);
    image.setCorners((float) pointTopLeft.getX(), (float) pointTopLeft.getY(),              //UL
            (float) pointTopRight.getX(), (float) pointTopRight.getY(),                     //UR
            (float) pointBottomRight.getX(), (float) pointBottomRight.getY(),               //LR
            (float) pointBottomLeft.getX(), (float) pointBottomLeft.getY());                //LL
```

But the result it returns is this (which is not what I want):
[image]

Comment: image.setCorners() is skewing, but you want to crop right (which is done through image.crop())?

Comment: I want to crop with custom corners. As you can see the image is not fitting exactly into a rectangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first skew the image by shifting the bottom corners and the top right corner - this will result in a more rectangular shape. Then you can crop the image.

I tried it with this:

```
    Image image = new javaxt.io.Image(bufferedImage);

    // skew image
    image.setCorners(
            // keep the upper left corner as it is
            0,0, // UL

            // push the upper right corner more to the bottom
            image.getWidth(),20, // UR

            // push the lower right corner more to the left
            image.getWidth()-45,image.getHeight(), // LR

            // push the lower left corner more to the right
            55,image.getHeight()); // LL

    // crop image
    image.crop(80, 105, image.getWidth()-150, image.getHeight()-105);
```

And the result is this:

[image: result image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method `image.getSubImage(x1,y1,x2,y2)` so that you can crop. After this, you can skew it to the right amount.